# xattr command error while setting security attributes

Tags: linux, xattr

I was running following commands to set extended attributes, but it is giving `Could not set extended attribute. Operation not supported` error.

```
xattr set security.SMACK64 "*" /dev/null
xattr set security.SMACK64 "*" /dev/zero
```

While checing the source for xattr, it is calling `setxattr()` function for setting the attributes and this function is returning error. While checking about `setxattr()` API, it seems the security attributes are used by kernel security modules (Security Enhanced Linux). When checked `make menuconfig`, lot of options are there under "Security options". I have enabled all options under "Security options", but still facing the same issue.

I am using 3.10.17 kernel on IMX6 sabersd board. Can you guide me what options I have to enable under "security options" and after that any changes need to do in user space to fix "Could not set extended attribute. Operation not supported" error.

Answer (score 0):

The error was not observed after enabling following options in kernel configuration.

```
security options -> 
             Enable different security models : 
                       Simplified Mandatory Access Control Kernel support
                       Default securitymodule(Simplified Mandatory Access Control)
```